# haproxy with password protected SSL certificate unable to start

Tags: ssl, haproxy

I had haproxy setup on Ubuntu 14.04, where it ask me for password for ssl certificate.
Now I upgraded OS from 14.04 to 16.04, now my haproxy not starting as it do not ask for password prompt and it expect password for SSL certificate. I get following log in haproxy.log

```
Feb  6 20:59:30 HAProxy1 haproxy[26925]: [ALERT] 036/205930 (26925) : Fatal errors found in configuration.
Feb  6 20:59:30 HAProxy1 haproxy[26929]: Enter PEM pass phrase:
Feb  6 20:59:30 HAProxy1 haproxy[26929]: [ALERT] 036/205930 (26929) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:43] : 'bind *:1936' : unable to load SSL private key from PEM file '/etc/ssl/private/cloud.pem'.
Feb  6 20:59:30 HAProxy1 haproxy[26929]: Enter PEM pass phrase:
Feb  6 20:59:30 HAProxy1 haproxy[26929]: [ALERT] 036/205930 (26929) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:63] : 'bind 0.0.0.0:443' : unable to load SSL private key from PEM file '/etc/ssl/private/cloud.pem'.
Feb  6 20:59:30 HAProxy1 haproxy[26929]: [ALERT] 036/205930 (26929) : Error(s) found in configuration file : /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
Feb  6 20:59:30 HAProxy1 haproxy[26929]: [ALERT] 036/205930 (26929) : Fatal errors found in configuration.
```

haproxy.conf

```
listen stats
  bind *:1936 ssl crt /etc/ssl/private/cloud.pem
  mode http
  stats enable
  stats hide-version
  stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics
  stats uri /stats
```

I tried to find out way to ask password by changing /lib/systemd/system/haproxy.service, but did not worked.

```
[Unit]
Description=HAProxy Load Balancer
Documentation=man:haproxy(1)
Documentation=file:/usr/share/doc/haproxy/configuration.txt.gz
After=network.target rsyslog.service

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/haproxy
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/haproxy
Environment="CONFIG=/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg" "PIDFILE=/run/haproxy.pid" "EXTRAOPTS=-S /run/haproxy-master.sock"
ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/haproxy -f $CONFIG -c -q $EXTRAOPTS
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/haproxy -Ws -f $CONFIG -p $PIDFILE $EXTRAOPTS
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/haproxy -f $CONFIG -c -q $EXTRAOPTS
ExecReload=/bin/kill -USR2 $MAINPID
KillMode=mixed
Restart=always
SuccessExitStatus=143
Type=notify
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Please suggest way to solve this.